# Programmatically dismissing textfield keyboard with delegate

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have a viewController with this:

`@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{`

Then I have a textfield added programmatically like this in viewController.m:

```
UITextField*textFieldRounded=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
textFieldRounded.delegate = self;
```

In the same `.m` i have tried all of these:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
NSLog(@"returned?");
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; 
NSLog(@"returned?");
 return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
NSLog(@"returned?");
    return YES;

}
```

The keyboard appears fine when I click the text field, which is in a subview of the viewController. but pressing Done does nothing. The `NSLog` statements never appear, so these methods are never getting called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just barely had this question, maybe, but what I did was attached a tap gesture recognizer object to the view, made a instance method called clear keyboard:, and inside the function I put [whateverItIsThatOpenedTheKeyboard resignFirstResponder]; and that's it. Maybe you asking something totally different, but I thought I would try and help :)

Comment: thanks, i've seen your recommendation in other places too. it's worth a try.

Comment: @andrewx you've seen my reccomendation?

Comment: i meant i've seen the technique you mention here suggested in other places, but not likely by you.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the UITextField in .h file as an IBOutlet with property and synthesize it in .m file.

Comment: use IBOutlet even though there is no interface builder?

Comment: yes,you should in case there is no interface builder.check this link http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-iphone-development

Comment: IBOutlet is pointless if you are not using IB, its just a flag so that IB can pick which properties it can map to, but using properties could be a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

Add this delegate method to your code and run your app once again..